# How to create JSF outputLabel next to inputText

Tags: jsf, label, positioning, textfield

I am creating a few outputLabels and corresponding inputText components, but the Label always appears above the textfield. I haven't found any attribute controlling this so far.

How do I get the label next to the input?

Comment: I KNOW more than just basic HTML and CSS, but as I already wrote in my post, I just started with JSF, because I had to. I am at this point not familiar with all the components that JSF uses and in which HTML components they are converted to. 
IMHO it is quite unusual to "stack" components like JSF has done in my example. 'Basic' HTML as you said, which I do not seem to be capable of, does not stack components like JSF has done. As you should know, HTML usually strings components. 
And as far as I was concerned layouting with invisible tables is presumed to be outdated so I didn't think of this

Comment: Of course I can, but I haven't done that. This is how my code looks/looked like:
´ <h:outputLabel value="Vorname:" for="input_firstname"/>
    <h:inputText id="input_firstname" value="" />
    <h:outputLabel value="Organisation:" for="input_organisation"/>
    <h:inputText id="input_organisation" value=""/>´
And the output was, that the components where stacked. Which is quite unusual in terms of HTML

Comment: I'm sorry, you couldn't have known, that I just started with JSF. I deleted it from my original question because I did not want bore you all ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [PanelGrid](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_panelGrid.html), Which in turn generates TABLE tag in HTML.

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
   <h:outputLabel>Name:</h:outputLabel>
   <h:inputText/>

   <h:outputLabel>Email:</h:outputLabel>
   <h:inputText/>

   <h:outputLabel>Passowrd:</h:outputLabel>
   <h:inputSecret/>
</h:panelGrid>
```

Once you define the `columns=2` it inserts the components side by side in each cell respectively.
There is also `h:column` which you can use.
But you can not perform ROWSPAN and COLSPAN in JSF as in HTML, however if you still want ROWSPAN and COLSPAN you can go for 3rd party JSF component Libriries like [Primefaces](http://primefaces.org/),[Richfaces](https://www.jboss.org/richfaces)...

Comment: Yes, way more than HTML TABLE.